# JQuery Accordion wrong width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to use a table with JQuery UI Accordion.
Both header and contents should be tables with 3 columns of fixed width.
For some strange reason, the first column of the contents consumes all the space ignoring the css, although the header looks OK.
Here is my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qm12h9tL/

And here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#topics').accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        header:'.topic',
        content:'.lessons'
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.accordion-container {
    width:100%;
}

.topic, .lessons {
    width: 400px;
}

.name {
    width: 70%;
}

.cards {
    width:15%;
}

.percentage {
    width: 15%;
}
</style>
<div class="accordion-container">
    <table id="topics">
        <tbody class="topic" style="display:table;" id="t1">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Topic 1</td>
                <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
                <td class="percentage">100%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="lessons">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Lesson 1</td>
                <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
                <td class="percentage">100%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Edit1** I tried coding HTML like this:

```
<table id="topics">
        <tr class="topic">
            <td class="name">Topic 1</td>
            <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
            <td class="percentage">100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='lessons'>
            <td class="name">Lesson 1</td>
            <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
            <td class="percentage">100%</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Doesn't work either.

**Edit 2** I've never thought that adding more lessons to a topic would be a problem!
http://jsfiddle.net/qm12h9tL/11/

```
<table id="topics">
    <tbody id="t1">
        <tr style="display: table-row;" class="topic">
            <td class="name">Topic 1</td>
            <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
            <td class="percentage">100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="lesson">
            <td class="name">Lesson 1</td>
            <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
            <td class="percentage">100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="lesson">
            <td class="name">Lesson 1</td>
            <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
            <td class="percentage">100%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you revert to the previous version with the incorrect code formatting? I understand if you don't agree with the changes I made on the question, but at least you should let people run the code without having to visit an external site.

Comment: What I saw was the words crossed out and the same words written in their place - looked to me like edit for the sake of edit. I'll review it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you added a `display: table` property to your header (`<tbody>`) element. This screws up a part of the layout. When you delete it, it's jQuery UI's turn to screw up your layout. It adds a `display: block` to the `<tr>` element which turns into a block. I would advise you to set `display: table-row` to your `<tr>` element.

You're now facing another issue because jQuery adds a span with an icon inside your `<tr>` which renders as an extra cell.  Add this CSS :

```
table span
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

And that will fix it.

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qm12h9tL/8/

---

*Update: fixed `collapsible: true`*

Comment: It does fix the layout but accordion does not appear be be designed to use on a tbody statement. At least in Firefox and Chrome it does not behave as you would expect an accordion to behave. Edit: at the very least it's now selecting text all over the place even though it does collapse and expand. But more generally, I don't think it's good practice to add a display:none to items that are not supposed to be there at all.

Comment: That's right but it is a simple temporary workaround. And it seems to work fine in FF and in Chrome even if there is a small delay before the collapse.

Comment: This could be easily fixed using CSS rules on table elements.

Comment: Agreed with the temporary fix angle. I think the correct way to approach this though, would actually be to use nested tables and bind the JQuery stuff to an element that is allowed to contain a span. Nice workaround though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your display:table style attribute is screwing up the layout (on your first tbody tag). Perhaps it's a remnant of some copy/paste action?

Comment: even after removing `display: table` the columns seem to be distorted

Comment: I've added it in an attempt to fix the columns. Removing it doesn't work.

Comment: It being there screws up the table layout so it's making your problem worse. You can check this by looking at it without the jquery init code. JQuery inserts a span inside the tbody element which is not allowed to be there. So you're using the accordion in a manner it was not designed to be used in.

Answer (score 0):

A hack has been made as solution

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header{
  display: table-caption !important;
}
```

Please note **`display: table-caption;` does not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#topics').accordion({
  collapsible:true,
  header:'.topic',
  content:'.lessons'
 });
});
```

```css
.accordion-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
#topics{
  width: 400px;
}
.name {
  width: 70%;
}
.cards {
  width: 15%;
}
.percentage {
  width: 15%;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header{
  display: table-caption !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion-container">
  <table id="topics">
    <tbody class="topic" id="t1">
      <tr>
        <th class="name">Topic 1</th>
        <th class="cards">10 cards</th>
        <th class="percentage">100%</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="lessons">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Lesson 1</td>
        <td class="cards">10 cards</td>
        <td class="percentage">100%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with width=700px;
I've set width=400px because it looks better in JSFiddle.